# how to get seconds from java long, I'm storing it in mssql DB as bigint

Tags: java, sql, time

I store the long values in mssql using bigint so I could do something like this:

```
--@start and @end are bigint
set @duration = @start - @end
```

now I need some additional operation so I could get the duration in seconds, anybody knows how ?

Comment: Long values, bigint, seconds? What exactly are you trying and what do your values represent?

Comment: I store values of type long in mssql db as bigint, and I need to convert this long value into seconds

Comment: You still didn't tell us what those values *are*. That they are numbers is obivous but do they represent milliseconds, nanoseconds, days, fortnights, apples or oranges? Are they time values at all? You know, such things *are* helpful to answer the question :-)

Comment: :) well, it's long and I get it by using System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: actually I'm thinking know that probably it would be a better idea to do the conversion in java and send seconds to the sql

Comment: What you are looking for has nothing todo with java. Tags like mssql would be more useful, because that's something your DBMS needs todo.

Looks like you are creating stored procedures, so hint that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it really depends on what those values were .. you say Java long, so it makes me wonder if you're doing something like System.currentTimeMillis() and then shoving that value in the database.  If that's the case, then just dividing the duration by 1,000 would get you seconds.

More information in the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

...
/* "seconds" is the number of seconds sinced the epoch began. */
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: of course I could send seconds to sql and not bother with storing long values in sql, probably that's also a good idea, who knows